# Migrating from Exchange Server 2003 to Sendmail in Linux (squirrel mail)

Tags: exchange, sendmail, dovecot

I want to know that how do we migrate the emails from exchange server to Linux sendmail.

What are the precautions that we need to take to avoid the data loss?

Thanks,

G.Gopi Krishna

Answer (score -1):

Migrating from exchange to sendmail?

Hmm... Strange.

Most people migrate from sendmail/postfix to exchange. Exchange is more than just only email. You have calendar, notes, contacts, tasks, Global Catalog with all contacts from your domain, centralized privilege an account management from AD, users can set autoresponder and give other users authorization to their emails and calendar.

Exchange is piece of collaboration platform from Microsoft application stack.

When you want to migrate only email, you can write some script, that will query AD/LDAP for existing email accounts and create mailboxes on Linux box. And then Another script, that would get all email from exchange using IMAP or POP3.

Maybe it is possible to use some Exchange connector, but I haven't seen this kind of solution. Connectors are frequently used for migrate data to Exchange, not from Exchange.

Are you loose anything. YES, you lose Exchange functionality.

I found this on the web:

> SUSE Openexchange Server has MS
>   Exchange Server migration method. But
>   you need to buy this SUSE Linux
>   product.

Maybe [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ol2mbox/) will by usefull for you.